# Fetch records from other table in OpenERP 8(Odoo)

Tags: python, odoo

I have been using Odoo in my Ubuntu14.04.I am trying to fetch records that are contained in other tables based on the values entered in the field. Like I have a table as 'hr_employee' from which I am getting employee names through many2one field. Now on the basis of value of this field , I want to get the field value of other table('hr_contract') matching the values of employee names like we do in Joins. But I dont want to use the db cursor here. Is this can be done through the search function or is there any other thing that I can do. Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this thing with search method as follow,

```
contacts = self.env['hr.contact'].search([('employee_id','=',self.employee_id.id)])

for contact in contacts:
    wage = contact.wage
    ### add your code here
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. I want to get the 'hr_contract.wage' field value on the match where hr_contract.employee_id = hr_employee.id.